# How can I limit the max FPS for an app that doesn't have an FPS option

Tags: macos, display

I'm trying to limit the max framerate for multiple apps which don't have built-in FPS options. Is there any tool (terminal or app) which can set this?

I've tried searching, but haven't found anything.

I'm running macOS Sierra.

Comment: Some apps have hidden debug options you can use to yield time, foreground or background, which will also server to limit the fps; even if they don't have a dedicated fps control. [I work on the support team for one such app] You might be better asking the specific app maker.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no generic mechanism to limit FPS for any app. It is completely up to each app to decide how many times per second it redraws its display.